# How to disable the NBGit plugin on Netbeans from automatically adding git version control to all projects?

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans7.0

I´m using Netbeans 7.0.1 for PHP development and after installing the Git plugin (NBGit), all my projects started automatically using the Git version control.

I was reading http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html to see if I was doing something wrong but according to that I was supposed to, on each project, do "Versioning > Initialize Git Repository".

But the only thing I have is "Connect" and after that all my projects start using Git. It's all or nothing. 
How can I change this setting in order that only the projects I want get versioned?

(Under Mac OS 10.7)

Comment: Where the `.git` is created? Is a `.git` created for *all* of your projects or one `.git` within each one? In the latter case, did you try to declare only that project in NetBeans workspace, Initialize the git repo, and then add the others projects?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Netbeans to version 7.1 or (better) 7.2. Versions 7.1+ have [native Git support](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB71#Git_Support_Finalized). No plugin required. In my experience with these versions, non-git projects remain non-git until a repo is initialized or cloned.